# DatePicker only day and month

Tags: javascript, datepicker

thread who encountered this problem?
Should that be the standard INPUT display only the day and month. WITHOUT year.

There date, datetime, datetime-local, month, time, week

They are not suitable.

Any idea what else?

Can such as through js year can disable the standard type = "date" ??

Comment: Did you have an editing problem? The question seems to start in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: @MackieeE—yeah, this question has jQuery all over it…

Comment: There are [*various types of date input*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime.html), however there isn't one for day and month. There is date, datetime, month (month and year) and time. Also, there are not many browsers that support date inputs, much less the other variants.